# "as +infinitive "

Tags: grammar

1) I do not think that they are uninvolved and innocent; I do not know. But why must that reason be so clear cut as to be the fact
that they were involved.

2) how are we so easily persuaded as to
believe that there isn’t something amiss?

Please consider these two sentences.I haven't been able to understand the meaning of  - "as +to " in those sentences. what's is the meaning of "as" here. Please explain the sentences to me.

Comment: Where did you see those sentences? Are you sure about "uninvolved"?

Comment: The first example is either from a non-native speaker, or from a native Anglophone with limited writing skills unsuccessfully trying to use a formal register.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is "so {X} as to be " {Y}.

The {characteristic X} is possessed to a degree sufficient to allow or to result in situation Y.

> It cannot be so easy as to be within the abilities of any
>   sophomore in high school. The graduate school entry exam must be more
>   difficult than that.
>
> The stage whisper called for in this scene must not be so quiet as to
>   be unheard by all but those who are sitting in the front rows.

An alternative would be a *that*-clause.

> It cannot be so easy that it is within the abilities of any
>   sophomore in high school.
>
> The stage whisper must not be so quiet that it is unheard by all
>   but those who are sitting in the front rows.

Thus, "so {x} as to be" is the  semantic equivalent of "so {x} that it is" or "so {x} that it would be".